# How do I change the direction of mesh lines in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient-mesh

I'm creating an object that has the mesh. I want the mesh lines to travel in a particular direction, but when I set them up they default to another direction. Is there a way to change this without distorting the object itself (ie since the mesh lines are attached to the object line)?

[image: Here's an image. I want to put a mesh in the oval. But I want the lines to point tin the same direction as the line I put next to the oval.]

Comment: it's difficult to answer without visuals. Meshes can be unwieldy at times depending upon how they are created. Sometimes you can edit easily, other times you can't.

Comment: I can't see where to add an image in this thread.

Comment: Hi Julie, Click the [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/127294/edit) link under your question... you'll see a formatting bar.. you can click the image icon there... [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqK9U.png)

Comment: Just figured it out. Above you can see the image now along with a description.

Comment: Oh, you got it `:)` So which lines are you trying to change? That seems like a fairly straight-forward mesh.

Comment: I want the mesh lines to point in the same direction as the line next to the oval.

Comment: Okay, that's not going to happen. Meshes are bound by their overall shape. But.. there may be another solution.. I'll write an answer.... which may or may not be helpful.

Comment: Is there another way you suggest I do this?

Comment: Excuse me, but there exists simpler ways to draw a bowling ball and its finger holes. No gradient meshes are needed, you can use simple linear and radial gradients.

Answer (score 2):

Per comments..

If you want something more like a "ball" then you have *far too many* mesh lines. You only need 1 mesh point to pull off a "ball" appearance...

[image]

Actually, this could also be done with a simple **radial gradient**. There's really no need for a mesh specifically with a simply "ball" shape.

---

With original information....

Assuming you want a circle with straight mesh lines similar to this....

[image]

The best way I can think to pull that off is via a **Clipping Mask** along with a **square mesh**.

Create a square mesh like so.....

[image]

This allows you to keep the mesh lines parallel and adjust them as desired.

Now draw a circle *on top* of the mesh...

[image]

Select the circle *and* the mesh and then choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu.

[image]

You can then rotate the circle so the mesh lines are at the angle you want...

[image]

Because it's merely a mesh with a clipping mask, you can use the **Mesh Tool** or the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to go in and alter the mesh further if desired.

[image]

---

This is essentially using the circle shape to *hide* portions of the mesh outside that shape. This is about the only way you'll get straight mesh lines on a circle. Any circle converted to a mesh is always going to follow the boundaries of the circle itself.

---

Comment: Thanks, I want this to be more three-dimensional though. More specifically, I'm looking to make this concave, like the hole in a bowling ball.

Comment: Then you probably *don't* want mesh lines to be straight. You really *want* them to follow the shape as in your screenshot.

Comment: Right, but they're pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: @julie1013 No. :) they are in the correct direction for the shape. You simply have way too many mesh points... see updated answer.

Comment: I want them in a different direction because of the way the ball is tilted so that it's consistent with the light source.

Comment: Sorry @julie1013 I can't seem to envision what it is you are expecting of a mesh. I don't think you will be able to achieve what you want with a mesh simply applied to a circle. From the sounds of things you may need to use multiple objects on top of a circle to create the appearance you want.. but again.. I have no clue what you are envisioning specifically.

Comment: Just imagine rotating the mesh within the oval... without changing the shape of the oval itself.

Comment: @julie1013 I've *specifically* shown how to do that in my answer.. which is why I cant' seem to follow what you are envisioning. Meshes are **attached** to the outer shape.. you can't "rotate the lines" without also changing the outer shape. That's simply not how meshes function.

Comment: Right you rotated the direction, but now the lines are straight.

Comment: So rather than a square mesh.. use another round mesh.

Comment: A mesh on top of a mesh?

Comment: You **can** do that.. or you can use a round clipping mask on a round mesh object.